# How to generate Blazor wasm scaffolded CRUD (EF) wiht ASP.NET Core Hosted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-webassembly, scaffolding

I'm looking how to create scaffolded blazor **components**.

I'm already know how to create it on a blazor server app, and I want to do the same on a wasm application, but can find the way. My blazor wasm is "ASP.NET Core Hosted" (and PWA), so y have a Backend project (and a "Shared one") who have all the controllers and manage the EF data context.

On VS, when you generated a new blazor wasm project with ASP.NET Core hosted, it creates 3 projects: the client component (wasm itself), the server component (data access), and the shared component (models)

I have EF core and the dbcontext in the *server* project, and the model in the *shared* project, but can find how to create all the CRUD components on the *client* project.

On a Blazor server i can do it like this:

[image: blazor server scaffolded]

Then:
[image: razor pages using EF CRUD]

Finally:

[image: select model and data context]

And then it creates something like this:

[image: created CRUD]

But there are all ".cshtml" and like this:

[image: blazor server create example]

And I want blazor components similar to the auto-generated weather component:

[image: weather component template]

If i select "Razor Component" in the "Add New Scaffolded Item", all I get is a empty component.

I've been googling a lot and I can't find anything that helps me to generate this, maybe it's not possible, I don't know, or maybe I'm not understanding something.

Edit1: clarification on the wasm "ASP.NET core hosted"

Edit2: added more details about the type of project I'm using

Comment: WASM code will run on the client, not the server and the client will not have access to the database (running on the server) so I'm not sure if scaffolding would be able to work the same way, even through SignalR.  To interact with data/entities, you would either need server rendering for that more direct-style binding, or have your WASM models request data from the server.  I'm not that deep into Blazor quite yet, so there very well may be options that others know of that might just not be available through the scaffolding.

Comment: Thank you both, I forgot to explain some things, my blazor wasm is "ASP.NET Core Hosted" (and PWA), so y have a Backend project (and a "Shared one") who have all the controllers and manage the EF data context. I'll edit my question to clarify this. My hope was that the scaffolding can work through the server project, may be that's not possible

Comment: You misunderstood what's involved and what an SPA, not just Blazor WASM, does. Blazor WASM works on the browser. There's no database there. It can only talk to the server through an HTTP API. That's what the HttpClient class does. EF Core on the other hand runs on the Server project, on the server and can only be used to provide data for the HTTP API (eg Web API) you want to use to feed the SPA. The `Razor Pages` wizard you tried to use can only generate classes in a single Razor Pages project. That's not the case here at all

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I already know what you are saying. Blazor wasm run on the browser, yes, but can communicate to the backend using hub or api (and the backend is where EF is). I think that I didn't explain too well, and I just assumed some things on my question (like the projects components VS auto generate). What I want is a way to generate the blazor crud component on the "client" project for each of the entities in the model (the model is on the "shared project"). I already generate it.

Comment: Blazor is still kind of new, there is no CRUD page generation yet. And I doubt if its on the feature list at all. When you need (lots of) CRUD pages, use MVC or Razore pages. Then use Blazor for the more interesting parts of your App.

Comment: With the new .NET 8 this can be done :)
https://youtu.be/YwZdtLEtROA?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oULyHSPBx-tQzePOYlhvrAU&t=2715

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to run EF in blazor-wasm. You should use API for transfer data or use blazor-serverside instead.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to explain some things, my blazor wasm is "ASP.NET Core Hosted" (and PWA), so y have a Backend project (and a "Shared one") who have all the controllers and manage the EF data context. I'll edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: then you can use the scaffolder to generate the correct controllers in the server project and call the APIs from the client project, just choose API controller with EF or the one with custom actions

Comment: Thanks Ivan, what I am trying to get is the .razor component pages. I already have the API controller (I did exactly what you said).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a blazor server app with the same ef db context and use it to generate your scaffolded Razor html ui and then paste that to the wasm app and replace the Ef specific code with calls to a web service on your server side project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new item template for file extensions and applying your scaffolding options to that see here:
[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2022)